# java.util.Date bean of type could not be found

Tags: java, spring

Spring Boot Application is failing on runtime with the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.bla.Application.Domain.SomeJavaClass required a bean of type 'java.util.Date' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.util.Date' in your configuration.
```

I am using:

1. Spring Boot (v1.5.8.RELEASE)
2. STS4 IDE
3. Java 8
4. Linux Ubuntu 18

**user@host:~$** java -version 
    *openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)

    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)*

I reinstalled Java completely, the error is still the same... 
Problematic Class:

Problematic Class is located in the domain model:

```
package com.vip.SmartScheduler.Domain;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.vip.SmartScheduler.Enum.PeriodUnit;

@Component
public class PeriodContainer {

    private Date periodBeginTimestamp;
    private List<UserStats> agentsWithStatistics;
    private PeriodUnit periodUnit;

    public PeriodContainer(Date periodBeginTimestamp, List<UserStats> agents, PeriodUnit periodUnit){
        this.periodBeginTimestamp = periodBeginTimestamp;
        this.agentsWithStatistics = agents;
        this.periodUnit = periodUnit;
    }

    public Date getPeriodBeginTimestamp() {
        return periodBeginTimestamp;
    }

    public void setPeriodBeginTimestamp(Date periodBeginTimestamp) {
        this.periodBeginTimestamp = periodBeginTimestamp;
    }

    public List<UserStats> getAgentsWithStatistics() {
        return agentsWithStatistics;
    }

    public void setAgentsWithStatistics(List<UserStats> agents) {
        this.agentsWithStatistics = agents;
    }

    public PeriodUnit getPeriodUnit() {
        return periodUnit;
    }

    public void setPeriodUnit(PeriodUnit periodUnit) {
        this.periodUnit = periodUnit;
    }

}
```

Comment: show this class `Application.Domain.SomeJavaClass`

Comment: where is your code? Hard to say what is going on without a code sample of the offending issue.

Comment: @locus2k - I think the problem is not in the code itself. I think this is an issue with the java configuration.  Code compiles successfully on other machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you class in question has parameters for its constructor but you have no beans defined for your parameters

You can do a couple things:

**Define your beans**

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeans {

  @Bean
  public Date periodBeginTimestamp() {
    return new Date();
  }

  @Bean
  public List<UserStats> agents() {
    return new ArrayList<UserStats>();
  }

  @Bean
  public PeriodUnit periodUnit() {
    return new PeriodUnit();
  }

}
```

This will create the necessary beans to inject into your parameters, but not sure if this will give you the control you want to populate the values with.

**Zero Arg Constructor**

The other way would be create a zero arg constructor then have a method to set what you need:

```
@Component
public class PeriodContainer {

  private Date periodBeginTimestamp;
  private List<UserStats> agentsWithStatistics;
  private PeriodUnit periodUnit;

  public PeriodContainer(){}

  public void setValues(Date periodBeginTimestamp, List<UserStats> agents, PeriodUnit periodUnit){
    this.periodBeginTimestamp = periodBeginTimestamp;
    this.agentsWithStatistics = agents;
    this.periodUnit = periodUnit;
  }

  ...
}
```

Then were you need it:

```
@Service
public class MyClass {
  @Autowire
  private PeriodContainer container;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    Date periodBeginTimestamp = getTimeStamp();
    List<UserStats> agents = getUserStatsList();
    PeriodUnit periodUnit = getPeriodUnit();
    container.setValues(periodBeginTimestamp, agents, periodUnit); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have not created a `java.Util.date` bean. If so, follow the steps [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-pass-a-date-into-bean-property-customdateeditor/) for the right way of injecting the Date bean without errors. If this is not the case, please add your bean configuration file (or a maven pom.xmlm or equivalent) to help understand the issue.